# Session usage in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session

I have a helper class for session,

```
namespace ShopCart.BAL
{
    public static class SessionHelper
    {
        public static ShopUser myShopUser
        {
            get
            {
                return HttpContext.Current.Session["myShopUser"] as ShopUser;
            }

            set
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Session["myShopUser"] = value;
            }
        }


    }

}
```

Further ShopUser class looks like

```
public class ShopUser 
{

    public string LoginID { get; set; }
    public string SessionID { get; set; }

    public long UserId { get; set; }

    public long ShoppingCartId { get; set; }

    public bool? Status { get; set; }

}
```

Now I want to know how to set session for particular property?
SessionHelper.Status = false;  //it creates a new property in SessionHelper
How to use above classes to create Sessions?

@mohsen your answer is correct. 
Further,

```
public ActionResult Index() {
 ShopLogin objShopLogin = new ShopLogin (); 
objShopLogin .checkUser();
 }

public class ShopLogin {
   public string checkUser() 
  { 
     SessionHelper.myShopUser.Status = false;
  }
}
```

So as you can see, I am creating class object here, as ShopLogin objShopLogin = new ShopLogin (); 
Can you tell me, can I use dependency injection here to avoid creating class objects like these?

Comment: Thanks @mohsen, it works. Can you tell me how to add dependency injection (nInject), so that I don't need to create "new" object.

 ShopUser objShopUser  = new ShopUser ();
 public string checkUser()
        {
SessionHelper.myShopUser.Status = false; 
}

Comment: public ActionResult Index()
        {
           ShopUser objShopUser = new ShopUser (); 
    objShopUser.checkUser();
    }

And then 
     public class Login
    {
        public string checkUser()
        {
      SessionHelper.myShopUser.Status = false;
        }
}

I want to avoid creation of class object like 
`  ShopUser objShopUser = new ShopUser ()`


Can I use dependency injection here(nInject) to avoid creating new object and achieve the same functionality

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: Please insert your code in question not in comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
SessionHelper.myShopUser.Status = false
```

**Edit**

Yes . Just add `static` modifier to `CheckUser` method

```
public ActionResult Index() {
 ShopLogin.checkUser();
 }

public class ShopLogin {
   public static string checkUser() 
   { 
       SessionHelper.myShopUser.Status = false;
   }
}
```

Comment: if (SessionHelper.myShopUser.Status == null) throws nullreference exception

Comment: checkUser() is in different class, it is in "Login"

So SessionHelper.myShopUser.checkUser(); will not work

Comment: SessionHelper.myShopUser.Status = false; also throws nullreference exception

Comment: If it is in another class .why you wrote  `objShopUser.checkUser();` in `Index` method?

Comment: I edited the question, my mistake, it was earlier,
currently it is 
objShopLogin .checkUser();
where objShopLogin is an object of Login